# C with Eclipse on Ubuntu: why is an .exe and no linux executable created?

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers under Ubuntu 15.5. When I build an run my C-program the program

- the program executes without any errors/warnings
- delivers the expected output in the eclipse-console
- and generates an **.exe file** in the the debug folder

For me it is very much surprising that an .exe file is generated using an Linux OS (I thought these files can only be created under Windows?). How can I configure Eclipse to generate a typical Linux-executable instead?

Many thanks!

Comment: Extensions don't matter much in Linux IIRC. You can name an executable `something.exe` and it won't change how it runs...

Comment: @c650 Thank you! I was absolutely unaware of that! By the way, with your answer (to this basic question) you have just helped me fixing a bigger bug that has annoyed me for a couple of weeks by now. Cheers!

Comment: "the program executes without any errors/warnings ..." - Apparently it "generates a typical Linux-executable" already.  So what's you problem?

Comment: @Olaf "Apparently it generates a typical Linux-executable already": what is obvious to you may not obvious to others (including me). "So what's your problem?": My problem was that, due to my lack of knowledge, that I thought a Windows-executable rather than a desired Linux-executable was generated. However, c650 noticed that there was some lack of knowledge on my side and gave me the information I needed to clear things up for me.

Comment: It is obvious to everyone reading your text. He does not even know about programming! I cited the relevant part of your text, in case you did not read it carefully yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions don't matter much in Linux. You can name an executable `something.exe` and it won't change how it runs...